# Route.get() requires a callback function but got object string

Tags: javascript, express

I have gone through the other similar posts but not sure or experienced enough to relate the resolution suggestions on my project.
I have created a simple app with two main routes as part of my learning through a udemy course, however, i cannot get around this issue of Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object String]. I know that that main aim is to export the router object containing all the nested routes for a root route but the fact that the error is asking for a callback doesn't make sense to me. Also the source of the error is the route.js file in the main node_modules library, node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211:15.

Tried a new test controller, same issue when running that file even without importing any of the route files. Deleted the route.js file from the library, new error shows up, Error: Cannot find module './route'. Officially stuck.

Insights and suggestions would be absolutely appreciated .
I have added the route, controller and package.json files below for reference.

controller (app.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const Joi = require('joi');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yelp-camp-new')
    .then(
        console.log('Connected to YelpCamp New db')
    )
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(e);
    }
    );

app.get('view engine', 'ejs')
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.use(express.json()) // parse json api data
app.use(express.urlencoded(({ extended: true }))); // parse form data encoded in body
app.use(methodOverride('_method')); // method over-ride for post requests


//Session and flash
const sessionConfig = { 
    secret: 'Thi$i$m7secret',
resave: false, 
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie:{
   httpOnly: true, // extra layer of security
   _expires: Date.now() + 1000 *60*60*24*7,
   maxAge: 1000*60*60*24*7
}
};
app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(flash()); // flash middleware


// Serving Static files from public dir, like js and css files.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// importing the routes
const campRoute = require('./routes/campRoutes');
app.use('/campgrounds', campRoute);


// =========================
// error middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const {message = 'Something went wrong.', status = 500} = err;
    res.status(status);
    res.render('error', {err, status})
    next(err);
})


// middleware for all the other routes not defined in this app
app.use('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('This page does not exist')
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening on port 3000')
})
```

//==================================================================================================
route file (campRoutes.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// pott.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
//    const camps = await Campground.find({});
//    res.render('showAllCamps', {camps});

// });


router.get('/new', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('new');
});

router.post('/', async(req, res)=>{
    const {campground} = req.body;
    console.log(campground);
})

module.exports = router;
```

//==================================================================================================

```
package.json file

{
  "name": "yelpcamp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {

    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "ejs-mate": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "joi": "^17.11.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo when setting the views engine. You should write

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

instead of `get`.

Comment: Legend!! that fixed it, always the small little things. Thank You.